# Как изменить State не на прямую

Tags: reactjs

Что делаю: рендерю потомки в родителе с передачей обработчика событий событий в props

компоненты: заголовок h1 и 2 кнопки минус и плюс

Проблема: Я знаю что state на прямую менять нельзя, но в заголовке  напрямую меняю state через тернарный оператор, потому-что если этого не сделать  то state уходит в  минус (-1,-2,-3,-4 и тд).

как можно сделать рефакторинг этого кода? (React < 1 мес)

```js
import React  from 'react'
import ReactDOM  from 'react-dom'

class OutNumber extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
   super(props)
  
   this.state = {
     number: 0
   }
   this.handlePlus = this.handlePlus.bind(this);
   this.handleMunis = this.handleMunis.bind(this);
 };
 handlePlus(event){
   this.setState({number: ++this.state.number})
 };
 handleMunis(event){
   this.setState({number: --this.state.number})
 }
 render(){
  console.log (this.state.number)
   return <div>
      <h1 >{this.state.number < 0 ? this.state.number = 0 : this.state.number}</h1>
       <MinusButton handler ={this.handleMunis} />
       <PlusButton  handler ={this.handlePlus}/>
   </div>
 }

}
 const  MinusButton = (props) =>{
 return <button onClick ={props.handler} >Click Me!(Minus)</button>
}
 const  PlusButton = (props)=>{
  return <button onClick={props.handler}>Click Me!(Plus)</button>
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <OutNumber />,
    document.getElementById('content')
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем проверять на отрицательное значение при рендере, когда можно в `handleMinus` осуществить проверку без изменения состояния (ну это в качестве примера):

```
this.setState({
    number: ((this.state.number - 1) < 0) ? 0 : --this.state.number
})
```

Тем самым Вы не нарушите правила изменения состояния. И можно убирать проверку из `render()`. В Плюс данный код не нужен, так как значение будет 0 и оно увеличится

Comment: только лучше текущее значение number брать не из this.state, а из prevState